# Custom Vertex Attributes GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, attributes, vertex

I want to make a couple of vec4 vertex attributes in my shaders. I've done quite a bit of googling, but I can't seem to find consistent information for specifically what I want to do.

My goal here is to move skinning to the GPU, so I need a list of bones and weights per vertex, hence why I want to use vertex attributes. I have 2 arrays of floats that represent this data. Basically this:

```
    weightsBuffer = new float[vSize*4];
    indexesBuffer = new int[vSize*4];
```

The part that I can't consistently find is how to upload these and use them in the shader. To be clear, I don't want to upload all the position, normal and texture coordinate data, I'm already using display lists and have decided to keep using them for a few reasons that aren't relevant. How can I create the buffers and bind them properly so I can use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding your bone weights and indices is no different of a process than binding your position data. Assuming the data is generated properly in your buffers, you use [glBindAttribLocation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) to bind the attribute index in your vertex stream to your shader variable, and [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) to define your vertex array (and don't forget `glEnableVertexAttribArray`).

The exact code may vary, depending on whether you're using VAOs and VBOs (or just client buffers). If you want a more specific answer, you should provide your code and shader.

Comment: I wanted to use display lists, but I read the OpenGL spec and glVertrxAttribPointer doesn't work with them, so you're right. :)